# MongoDB C# Driver - Representing a list of string as list of ObjectId

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

So using MongoDB and it's C# driver, i have a many-to-many relationship between `Users` and `Projects` and have them referenced each other like this (based on this article - [many to many relationship](http://blog.markstarkman.com/blog/2011/09/15/mongodb-many-to-many-relationship-data-modeling/)):

```
public class User
{
    // other props....
    ICollection<string> ProjectIds {get; set;}
}

public class Project
{
    // other props....
    ICollection<string> UserIds {get; set;}
}
```

As you see, I used `string` instead of `ObjectId`. I know you can do this by using `SetRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectID)` in the mappings or via the data annotations but, with the list of strings, MongoDB throws a `BsonSerializationException`.

So, how can I tell MongoDB to represent a list of string as ObjectIds? Any input on this matter would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You mean you know how to do that for a single string and you're asking for a collection?

Comment: Yes, sorry if I didn't make that clear enough.

Comment: I don't think it's possible unless you write your own bson serializer which maps strings to objectIds.

Answer (score 0):

In mongodb I use `List<string>` it will store as an [] array in the collection and will work fine.